# Передача аргументов экземпляру класса

Tags: python

Как можно осуществить передачу аргумента (-ов) экземпляру класса в python?

Резонанс вызвал этот код:
`moment = Moment(app)`
`current_time = datetime.utcnow()`
`moment(current_time).fromNow(refresh=True)`

А именно `moment(current_time)`

P.S. Куски кода вырваны из книги Мигеля Гринберга про фласк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как пример, может быть так

```
class Moment:
    def __new__(cls, app):
        return M
```

или

```
class Moment:
    def __init__(self, app):
        return

    def __call__(self, current_time):
        return M(current_time)
```

для

```
from datetime import datetime

class M:
    def __init__(self, current_time):
        self.fromNow = lambda refresh: print(current_time)

app = None
moment = Moment(app)
current_time = datetime.utcnow()
moment(current_time).fromNow(refresh=True)  # 2020-08-05 11:33:24.631421
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы ищите магический метод `__call__(self, *arguments, **kwargs)`, который в вашем случае возвращает некий объект с методом `fromNow`.